# Exclamation mark before integer variable php

Tags: php

```
function test_function (int $a){
    
    if(!$a>0){
         echo "in";
    }else{
         echo "out"
    }

}

test_function(0);//output: in  
test_function(2);//output: out  
test_function(4);//output: out
```

I understand PHP's own operator precedence kicks in and "!" exclamation mark does the first calculation, prior to the "greater than" operator. That's okay.

I wish PHP would throw an error here saying "a boolean operation cannot be done on an integer". But in any case, the easy solution is to use parantheses:

```
if(!($a>0))
```

This takes care of precedence.
But in a large code base, do you have any additional suggestions to prevent mishaps?

Comment: You mean just the opposite `if($a <= 0){`?

Comment: I know I'm not the smartest guy around but I find your code confusing, it makes me wonder whether you're trying to handle some exceptional situation coming from PHP loose typing (null, empty strings, zeroes behaving as false...).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asked for it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The !-operator is the *not* operator from boolean algebra.
PHP tries hard to allow dynamic variable instantiation.

In your case `!$a>0` would result in "(not $a) > 0".
The second one would be `!($a>0)` would negotiate the outcome of `$a>0`.

Either ways are technically fine (and might make more sense than the other). If you really want to avoid to not negotiate non-integers, just check what you got:

```php
if (is_int($a) && !($a > 0)) {
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the `is_int()` approach. If data is totally bogus (`'foo'`) PHP itself will throw an error due to the `int` type hint. In other cases the function will no longer accept values that would otherwise be valid (`'123'`).

Answer (score 0):

You just need a very good modeling. As others pointed, the person in charge for defining that IF just need to be good at PHP. Depending on what logic needs implementation there, it is up to the coder find wheter or not it needs separete logic, as $variable>number will always return "true" or "false", look at the implementation of Michail Hirschler, it is a very good one.